# Finding all objects that extend non-sealed trait at compile time

Tags: scala, sbt

Let's say I have a non-sealed trait, Foo, and throughout my code I define some Objects that extend Foo.

Is there a way that I can, at compile time, look up all objects that extend Foo and print out some information about them (like printing out a string literal I have in a val?)

If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: You are considering non-separated compilation, right?

Comment: This sounds like a job for an annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an obscure feature to have and it has problems since a lot of times only a few pieces of your code are re-compiled (and it only get's worse with libraries and dependencies). If I where you, I would just "find in files" for `extends Foo` or `with Foo` and check the results. You can even do a small script with regex to extract your val for each result if you are willing to do that work.